# Sign of a convergent series given its first term is negative and all others positive

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose we are given a sequence of numbers $\{\beta_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ such that the corresponding series below converges absolutely (so that $\beta_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$):
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta_n$$
Suppose we are also given that $\beta_0<0$ and $\beta_n>0$ for each $n=1,2,\dots$.

My question is this: If we suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\beta_n>0$, does this necessarily imply that there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^m\beta_n>0$ for every $m\ge N$? Or is there a counterexample to this?

Comment: If I understand your assertion correctly, it has to be true.  Each $b_1, b_2, \cdots$, is positive, and the overall summation converges to a positive value.  Therefore, the summation is strictly increasing and *converging* towards a positive $L$.  Therefore, the *tail* of the series must contribute a negligible amount, that becomes more and more negligible as you go farther out on the series.

Comment: In fact, the condition that each $b_1, b_2, \cdots$ is positive is **not needed**.  All that is needed is [1] the limit $L$ is strictly > 0 and [2] you consult the definition of a convergent series.  Perhaps you could edit your query to include the definition, and try (in your edited query) to prove the assertion.  For example, if $r = (L/2)$, wouldn't there have to be a point in the series beyond which, the running total **permanently remains** in a neighborhood of radius $r$ around $L$.

Comment: Regarding the analysis $\varepsilon$ definition of a convergent series, one can just look that up, but your reasoning definitely does help. Thanks!

Comment: The point is **not** for you to *look that up* but [1] Take it straight out of your textbook/class-notes (assuming that you are studying this topic) [2] Consult the theorems and previously solved problems and worked examples in the book/class that have led up to this point, and then [3] edit your query, in accordance with [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).